# Requirements of a matrix to have all eigenvalues either pure imaginary or pure real

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A real matrix, $\mathbf{P}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, is constructed from a multiplication of two matrices: $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{JH}$, where the matrix $\mathbf{H}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is a real-symmetric matrix, and

$$
\mathbf{J} = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} \\ -\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} \end{pmatrix}
$$

is a skew-symmetric matrix with $\mathbf{I}$ being the identity matrix.
What are the requirements for the matrix $\mathbf{H}$ such that the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{P}$ are either pure real or pure imaginary?

For $2\times 2$ matrix ($n=1$), the matrix $\mathbf{P}$ automatically have the eigenvalues pure real or pure imaginary, so no additional conditions needed apart from the ones specified above.
However, for $n>1$, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: A simple case is when $H_{11}=-H_{22}$ and $H_{12}=H_{12}^T$. Then, in this case $JH$ is symmetric and the eigenvalues are all real.

Comment: Similarly if $H_{11}=H_{22}$ and $H_{12}^T=-H_{12}$ the matrix $JH$ is skew symmetric and the eigenvalues are purely imaginary.